# C# assign to dictionary upon instantiating

Tags: c#, .net

What's the best way to assign to a dictionary when instantiating?

For example, how can I do to `myDictionary` below what I've done with `myList`?

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    // this does not work. how to make it work?
    (0, "first"),
    (1, "second")
};

// here's how it's done with List<T>
List<Int32> myList = new List<int>(){
    1,
    2,
    3
};
```

Comment: Change the parentheses to curly braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    {0, "first"},
    {1, "second"}
};
```